# Editing CSS through JavaScript produces left-hand assignment error

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm trying to create a list that when an item is clicked, the item is strike-throughed (grammar?). However, I am getting the following error: `SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side`. I am new to web development so I am unfamiliar with the debugging process.

I originally structured my code by passing a function that would strike the item, but that did not work. For reference, the function getForm() gets input from an input box and appends it to a  displayed below the input box.

```
function getForm() {
.
.
.
/* Append the input to the list */
    var node = document.createElement("LI"); // Create a <li> node
    node.setAttribute("onclick", "strikethroughItem(this.id)"; // call func on click
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.name); // Create a text node
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node); // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList"
}
function strikethroughItem(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.text-decoration = "line-through";
}
```

In an attempt to see if this was a problematic approach, I adjusted it to be edited directly, like so.

```
function getForm() {
/* Append the input to the list */
    var node = document.createElement("LI"); // Create a <li> node
    node.setAttribute("onclick", "document.getElementById(this.id).style.text-decoration = 'line-through'"); // call func on click
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(task.name); // Create a text node
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node); // Append <li> to <ul> with id="myList" 
}
```

However, it produces the same error.

Comment: `[...].style.text-decoration` is invalid; `text-decoration` is not a valid JS identifier. It should be `textDecoration`. You're basically saying `[...].style.text - decoration = xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in JavaScript functions and properties are written in camelCase. So when you write

```
document.getElementById(id).style.text-decoration = "line-through"
```

JavaScript sees the minus symbol (`-`) as a weird subtraction and assignment on the left hand side and gets a little crazy.

To resolve this, change it to use the correct style property.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration = "line-through"
```

You can view more info about styling via JavaScript at w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp) and a mapping between CSS and JavaScript properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference).

Comment: It might also be nice to include a link to the list of styles available to JS, which also maps between CSS and JS names, and isn't W3 because W3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference

Comment: Nice mapping! I was looking for something like that but couldn't find that page. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

CSS `text-decoration` should be written `textDecoration` in Javascript !

Answer (score 0):

`[...].style.text-decoration` is invalid; `text-decoration` is not a valid JS identifier. It should be `textDecoration`.

Explanation:

To JS you're saying `[...].style.text - decoration = xxx`.